# Get a property from the object

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
this.utils = {
    width: 200,
    doSomeWorkWithWidth: function(){
        // How to access width property from inside this code?
        console.log(width)
    }
}
```

I will need to change width property from outside then do some work with its value from inside the function. How can I access it from this function in a proper way?

The other thing is I am going to use `utils` object inside other more complex code where `this` will be assigned to another object, so `this.width` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use console.log( this.width );

Comment: @Sergei Basharov how do you call doSomeWorkWithWidth ?

Answer (score 1):

You use `this`:

```
var utils = {
    width: 200,
    doSomeWorkWithWidth: function(){
        // How to access width property from inside this code?
        console.log(this.width)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`, or `utils.width`

```js
var utils = {
    width: 200,
    doSomeWorkWithWidth: function(){
        // How to access width property from inside this code?
        console.log(this.width);
        // or
        console.log(utils.width);
    }
}

utils.doSomeWorkWithWidth();
```